# Unable to Parse following XML?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I have continuous tags of `img id="#"`, where `#` varies from 1 to 9.

The description of tags consists of floating values.

When I use the standard NSXML Parser, i not getting all the values.

My XML for reference:

```
<img id="1">-0.0111328,-0.0635608,0.152549,0.11211,-0.0250431,

            -0.0370875,0.0862391,0.0970791,-0.0195908,

            -0.00892297,0.0791795,0.0554013,0.00362028,0.0138572,0.0432729,

             0.0253036,-0.0770325,0.14065,0.118424,0.1787,

             0.0734354,0.160883,0.101831,0.237038,0.0681151,0.178331,

             0.106532,0.224731,0.133766,0.222096,0.165214,0.240752,

             -0.0280366,0.106239,0.052094,0.110642,   

</img>
```

How would I parse the above XML?

Kindly, help me out.

Thanx

Comment: Where's your code? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: also, please show what values you are able to get from your codes.

Comment: @MattBall after trying the following answer, i will surely post my whole answer either to get a solution or as a reference for others.

Comment: @MattBall will keep note of the recommendations next time postingany question

Comment: @ShivanRaptor will keep note of the recommendations next time posting any question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it... i placed start and end tags for img id = '#'. My structure now looks like this:

```
<images>

    <img id = '1'> -0.0111328,-0.0635608,0.152549,0.11211,-0.0250431,

        -0.0370875,0.0862391,0.0970791,-0.0195908,

        -0.00892297,0.0791795,0.0554013,0.00362028,0.0138572,0.0432729,

         0.0253036,-0.0770325,0.14065,0.118424,0.1787,

         0.0734354,0.160883,0.101831,0.237038,0.0681151,0.178331,

         0.106532,0.224731,0.133766,0.222096,0.165214,0.240752,

         -0.0280366,0.106239,0.052094,0.110642, ....  

     </img>

     <img id = '2'> ... 

     </img>

   ....

   ....

</images>

<mapping>

  <map>
    <imgid> 1 </imgid>
    <keyword> heavy </keyword>

  </map>

  <map>
    <imgid> 2 </imgid>
    <keyword> metal </keyword>

  </map>

  ...

  ...

</mapping>
```

Placing start and end tags allowed me to parse the whole xml.

Earlier, the start and end tags were for individual images which only resulted in parsing of one img.

This made me add another key point while parsing XML.

Hope this helps others as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `parser:foundCharacters:` does not deliver all characters at once. You need to concatenate all strings that you get between the callbacks of the `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` and `parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:` that you get for the `<img>` tag.

In the code below, `buf` is an `NSMutableString` ivar of your parser delegate.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([qualifiedName isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
        buf = [NSMutableString string];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([qualifiedName isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
        buf = [buf stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        NSLog(@"Got %@", buf);
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    [buf appendString:string];
}
```